# How much does (or can) the fuselage of a long aircraft flex?

Tags: fuselage

How much will the unsupported ends of an airliner's fuselage droop in level flight?

In turbulence, how much vertical movement will they experience relative to the wing?

And finally, in extreme conditions, what is the expected limit of such movement?

Is it a movement of a few millimetres or a few centimetres, or more than that?

I assume any horizontal flex - or torsion along the axis - will be much smaller.